# How to get transactions history details of specific account using Ethereum API

Tags: transactions, ethereumj

How to get transactions history details of specific account using Ethereum API

currently i am using Ethereum API got get list of transactions based on ontract address, but i need full details of each transaction as well to populate on my dashboard. 
this is the example which i am using for to populate list of transactions:

https://api-ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x39659330d4a4f25743569e58c11d4f838d4ce68b&sort=asc

please help me if any endpoint to get individual transaction details using Ethereum API?

Thanks